# SyntaxError when try to run javascript on raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I am building an IoT application using Arduino and raspberry pi.there is a requirement which is read the serial output from Arduino. this reading is done by the raspberry. for this process, I am using node serial port module.

When reading that serial output there is a condition that I have to use. I only need the one line which contains the integer value.so I used the following code lines for that.

[picture: in here you can see the integer contained line.since this is a loop you can see several lines.I need read that line once for a loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glojs.jpg)

```
var sp = new serialport("/dev/ttyACM0", { //for serial communication with arduino 
    //baudrate: 9600,  
    baudRate: 9600,
// we are using UNO so baudrate is 9600, you might need to change according to your model
 //parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
 parser: new Readline("\r\n") 

    if(data === parseInt(data,10)){

        dataTemp = data;


    }


});
```

as you can see I used that if condition to check whether that line is an integer or  not.but when I execute this using putty the console reply me following:

[picture:putty output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6FIr.jpg)

```
/home/pi/indigo-parking.js:24
        if(data === parseInt(data,10)){
        ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
```

so I am wondering anyone could help me to go through this.if you have any idea/solution please be kind enough to share with me. (i have included the full code below...you can refer that to get a better idea)

full code for raspberry:

```
//indigo parking data transfer
var webSocketUrl = "wss://api.artik.cloud/v1.1/websocket?ack=true";
var device_id = "861b8f68ff30439288d755b5e7a74374"; // Indigo parking DEVICE ID
var device_token = "0f8681a1bd624624b6d4841358f323c2"; //Indigo parking DEVICE TOKEN
// import websocket module
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var isWebSocketReady = false;
var data="";
var dataTemp="";
var ws = null;
// import serialport module
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var Readline = serialport.parsers.Readline
//const port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty-usbserial1')

var sp = new serialport("/dev/ttyACM0", { //for serial communication with arduino 
    //baudrate: 9600,  
    baudRate: 9600,
// we are using UNO so baudrate is 9600, you might need to change according to your model
 //parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
 parser: new Readline("\r\n") 

    if(data === parseInt(data,10)){

        dataTemp = data;


    }


});


var parking_state=0;// variable to check for parking state_gate
// this is for demo purpose only


/**
 * Gets the current time in millis
 */
function getTimeMillis(){
    return parseInt(Date.now().toString());
}

/**
 * Create a /websocket connection and setup GPIO pin
 */
function start() {
    //Create the WebSocket connection
    isWebSocketReady = false;
    ws = new WebSocket(webSocketUrl);
    ws.on('open', function() {
        console.log("WebSocket connection is open ....");
    // after creating connection you have to register with your Authorization information
        register();
    });
    ws.on('message', function(dataTemp) {
      //this loop is called whenever the client sends some message
         handleRcvMsg(dataTemp); //data is received to the function handleRcvMsg()
    });
    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log("WebSocket connection is closed ....");

    });      

}

/**
 * Sends a register message to /websocket endpoint
 */
//Client will only work when device gets registered from here
function register(){
    console.log("Registering device on the WebSocket connection");
    try{
        var registerMessage = '{"type":"register", "sdid":"'+device_id+'", "Authorization":"bearer '+device_token+'", "cid":"'+getTimeMillis()+'"}';
        console.log('Sending register message ' + registerMessage + '\n');
        ws.send(registerMessage, {mask: true});
        isWebSocketReady = true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error('Failed to register messages. Error in registering message: ' + e.toString());
    }    
}


//data after receiving is sent here for processing
function handleRcvMsg(msg){
    var msgObj = JSON.parse(msg);
    if (msgObj.type != "action") return; //Early return;

    var actions = msgObj.dataTemp.actions;
    var actionName = actions[0].name; //assume that there is only one action in actions
    console.log("The received action is " + actionName);

    //you must know your registered actions in order to perform accordinlgy
    // we will not receive any action in our case
    if (actionName.toLowerCase() == "parking_state") 
    { 
       // your code here 
    }
    else {
         //this loop executes if some unregistered action is received
         //so you must register every action in cloud
        console.log('Do nothing since receiving unrecognized action ' + actionName);
        return;
    }

}



/**
 * Send one message to ARTIK Cloud
 */
//This function is responsible for sending commands to cloud
function sendStateToArtikCloud(parking){
    try{
        ts = ', "ts": '+getTimeMillis();
        var dataTemp = {
            "indigolot": parking
//setting the parking value from argument to our cloud variable "parking"
//we will get the value from arduino
            };
        var payload = '{"sdid":"'+device_id+'"'+ts+', "data": '+JSON.stringify(dataTemp)+', "cid":"'+getTimeMillis()+'"}';
        console.log('Sending payload ' + payload + '\n');
        ws.send(payload, {mask: true});
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error in sending a message: ' + e.toString() +'\n');
    }    
}



function exitClosePins() {

        console.log('Exit and destroy all pins!');
        process.exit();

}


start();
//exectes every time when data is received from arduino (30sec programmed delay from arduino)
sp.on("open", function () {
    sp.on('data', function(dataTemp) {

            console.log("Serial port received data:" + dataTemp);
            //sendStateToArtikCloud(data);//parking data to artik cloud
            sendStateToArtikCloud(dataTemp);

    });
});


process.on('SIGINT', exitClosePins);
```

Comment: That's in an object literal, and you have that `if` line just floating. What's it supposed to be inside of?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.yes you are correct I did it wrong.i have to wrap the parser by a function. then it did work.thanks again for your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it clearly a Syntax error?

```
var sp = new serialport("/dev/ttyACM0", {
    baudRate: 9600,
    parser: new Readline("\r\n") 
    if(data === parseInt(data,10)){//// this line////
        dataTemp = data;
    }
});
```

The serialport constructor accepts an object as the second argument. You are writing an `if` clause inside an object.

Don't know about serial port but if parser accepts function you can wrap a function around it. or maybe use an iife

```
parser: (function(){
    let data = new Readline("\r\n") 
    if(data === parseInt(data,10)){
        dataTemp = data;
        return dataTemp;
    })();
```

Or something like that

Comment: thank you very much, @aritra-chakraborty! I tried your solution and it did work after making a few changes to the script. I am kind of new to this thing.so I learned a new thing today thanks to you. I'll post the solution below.so then it will be a great help to whoever facing this kind of problem. 

`var sp = new serialport("/dev/ttyACM0", { 
baudRate: 9600,
according to your model
parser: function(){
 let data = new Readline("\r\n")
 if(data === parseInt(data,10)){
        dataTemp = data;
        return dataTemp;
 }
} 
});`